# Odd handling of NA in glm

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, dataset, missing-data

When importing a CSV file that was exported from SAS, I forgot to put the **na.strings = "."** option in the read.table function.  It took me a while to find the error, but what struck me was the radical change in the logistic regression results when I got it right.  This was further complicated by the fact that only two values of the outcome were actually missing.

What is disturbing is the radical change in the estimates with only two faulty outcome values with 568 observations.  I've tried coding the missing values as 1 or 0, without being able to recreate the result with just two dots in the data.  Any ideas as to what it's doing?  I'd like to teach this as a cautionary tale of improper data reading, but would like something beyond "shit happens". Thanks.

**The wrong way:**

```
HTNdataX <- read.table("C:/Users/David/Dropbox/BS821/HTN.csv",
+             sep="\t")

> names(HTNdataX) <- c("hypertension","age")
> summary(HTNdataX)
 hypertension      age    
 .:  2        Min.   :13  
 0:510        1st Qu.:28  
 1: 56        Median :35  
              Mean   :36  
              3rd Qu.:44  
              Max.   :62  
> logregHx <- glm(hypertension ~ age, family=binomial(link="logit"),data=HTNdataX)
> summary(logregHx)

Call:
glm(formula = hypertension ~ age, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = HTNdataX)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-3.14237   0.01467   0.02957   0.07280   0.43184  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  14.7469     5.5922   2.637  0.00836 **
age          -0.2003     0.1059  -1.891  0.05860 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 26.589  on 567  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 20.970  on 566  degrees of freedom
AIC: 24.97

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 10
```

**The right way:**

```
 HTNdata <- read.table("C:/Users/David/Dropbox/BS821/HTN.csv",
+             sep="\t", na.strings = ".")
> names(HTNdata) <- c("hypertension","age")
> head(HTNdata,10)
   hypertension age
1             0  32
2             0  40
3             0  34
4             1  29
5             0  37
6             0  20
7             0  30
8             0  22
9             0  36
10            0  27
> 
> summary(HTNdata)
  hypertension          age    
 Min.   :0.00000   Min.   :13  
 1st Qu.:0.00000   1st Qu.:28  
 Median :0.00000   Median :35  
 Mean   :0.09894   Mean   :36  
 3rd Qu.:0.00000   3rd Qu.:44  
 Max.   :1.00000   Max.   :62  
 NA's   :2                     
> 
> 
> logregH <- glm(hypertension ~ age, family=binomial(link="logit"),data=HTNdata)
> summary(logregH)

Call:
glm(formula = hypertension ~ age, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = HTNdata)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.8458  -0.5004  -0.3933  -0.3142   2.5073  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.42920    0.59612  -7.430 1.09e-13 ***
age          0.05783    0.01421   4.071 4.68e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 365.35  on 565  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 347.83  on 564  degrees of freedom
  (2 observations deleted due to missingness)
AIC: 351.83

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536), it won't be possible to figure this out. Can you provide one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how R works without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

This is *not* about handling missing values, but about putting garbage data into your model. You have read your data as a three-level factor with levels:

```
 hypertension 
 .:  2         
 0:510        
 1: 56
```

In case of factors, [R interprets them as following](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/family.html) (see `?family`)

> ‘success’ is interpreted as the factor not having the first level (and
>   hence usually of having the second level).

So in the first case you predicted you modeled data with 510 successes (`0`) and 2 failures (`.`), while in the second case 56 successes and 510 failures. This is reflected in your intercepts ("base rate", notice that $\beta_1$'s are close), that after inverse logit transformation are in the first case equal to $0.0117$ and in the second case to $0.9999$. You may also notice drastically different AIC values and a number of other differences that suggest that the models were dealing with different data as input. To check things like this you can always use `str` function on the `glm` objects to check their internal structure and the data as they have "seen" it.

Comment: Understood.  I had discounted the possibility of a 2 observations vs. the rest model as I would expect it to either blow up or give obviously wild results.  Running this in SAS [missing vs. the rest] gives similar mundane results and a c-statistic of 0.923.  Case closed.  Thanks.